# bootstrap panel

Tags: html, bootstrap

есть вот такая панель:

```
<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse1">Фільтр</a>
    </h4>
  </div>
  <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
    <div class="panel-body">
      ...
    </div>        
  </div>
</div>
```

как сделать так что бы содержимое в body отображалось сразу без нажатия, но если нужно по нажатию панель закрывалась? Ибо у меня там форма фильтра, и каждый раз как-то не удобно открывать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот сюда - class="panel-collapse collapse" - добавьте класс in

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)

Comment: тогда поставьте галочку возле ответа ))

Comment: еще 3 минуты, пока нельзя)